# SQL: Long to wide

Tags: sql

I have a SQL dataset including:

```
key - stage1_date - stage2_date - ... - stage5_date
xx    2022-02-01    2022-06-01           NULL
xxy   2022-10-25    2022-11-26           2023-05-01
```

covering a period of 18 months since **2022-01-01**.

I'd like to get this into the following format:

```
key - month_1 - month_2 - ...... - month_18
xx    stage_1   stage_1            stage_2
xxy   stage_1   stage_2            stage_5
```

I calculated the following:

```
CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,30,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,30,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_1
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,60,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,60,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_2
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,90,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,90,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_3
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,120,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,120,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_4
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,150,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,150,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_5
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,180,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,180,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_6
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,210,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,210,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_7
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,240,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,240,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_8
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,270,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,270,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_9
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,300,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,300,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_10
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,330,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,330,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_11
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,360,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,360,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_12
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,390,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,390,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_13
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,420,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,420,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_14
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,450,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,450,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_15
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,480,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,480,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_16
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,510,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,510,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_17
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,540,a.stage_1_date) <= getdate() THEN DATEADD(day,540,a.stage_1_date) else NULL End as month_18
```

so that I have date-boundaries to link the stages where available, but not sure how to go on from here.

Any help?

Thanks
Any advice on this?